# Reducer keep returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to return an array from the reducer after filling it with data, but it always returns an empty array.

```
export default function dashboards(state: any = dashboardsState, action: any) {
 // more code
  if (action.type === Types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_SUCCESS) {
    // create the cards holder in the store
    var cardsSkull: any = [];
    Object.keys(action.payload.lists).map((idLis: any) => {
      cardsSkull[idLis] = {};
      console.log("still up");
    });
    action.payload.importedDashboards.map((impDash: any) => {
      Object.keys(impDash.mappedLists).map((key: any) => {
        const mpList = impDash.mappedLists[key];
        cardsSkull[mpList.idlistLocal][impDash.remote_board_id] = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log("still working");
      });
    });
    console.log(cardsSkull);
    // assign and ready to go
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      selectedDashboardData: action.payload,
      cards: cardsSkull
    });
  }
// more code
return state;
}
```

when I `console.log(cardsSkull)` everything looks right.

[image]

I expect the `cards` to have the value of `cardsSkull` after it is filled, but the actual output is an empty array

Comment: try: cards: [...cardsSkull]

Comment: @F.bernal still the same result :/

Comment: It's strange, can you post your client code?

Comment: client code ? 
just for information `selectedDashboardData` returned with value , only `cards` empty

Comment: Try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(cardsSkull))` and report what you get. Console.log kind of observe changes in arrays...

Comment: it seems that you are using a little bit wrong intention with map even it does not affect to the result. To troubleshoot problem, can you post how your reducers were implemented? and how do you know the array was empty

Comment: @jpavel , it return [] !!

Comment: @ducmai , i know it from the react extension, the problem that  `selectedDashboardData`  returned with value, only cards returned empty

Comment: but your cards seems to be an object instead of an array. maybe it is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `cardsSkull` as array (which is an object under the hood), but because `idLis` is not a number, `cardsSkull[idLis] = {};` does not populate an element within the array part of the object, but rather an element within the array object itself. **Therefore in your screenshot, the `length` property of your array is still `0`!** Use numbers for `idLis` and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are assuming wrong type for cards, it is an object instead of array. I would suggest to update as following

```
export default function dashboards(state: any = dashboardsState, action: any) {
  // more code
  if (action.type === Types.LOAD_DASHBOARD_SUCCESS) {
    // create the cards holder in the store
    const cardsSkull = Object.keys(action.payload.lists).reduce(
      (acc, idLis) => ({ ...acc, [idList]: {} }),
      {}
    );    

    action.payload.importedDashboards.forEach((impDash: any) => {
      Object.keys(impDash.mappedLists).forEach((key: any) => {
        const mpList = impDash.mappedLists[key];
        cardsSkull[mpList.idlistLocal][impDash.remote_board_id] = [1, 2, 3];
        console.log('still working');
      });
    });
    console.log(cardsSkull);
    // assign and ready to go
    return {
      ...state,
      selectedDashboardData: action.payload,
      cards: cardsSkull
    }
  }
  // more code
  return state;
}
```

Comment: it's working, thanks, man.  tried a bunch of stuff without success and i forget to check my types again.